# Jetty fails to load with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I use Java 8-specific code

Tags: java, java-8, jetty

I'm using Jersey in an embedded Jetty web server. Everything works well, except in one very specific case. I have a list of users, and when the client `POST`s to /user, I'd like to add the user to the list. No problems, unless I want to check the existing users to delete any users who have the same username (in order to update the user).

```
@POST
public void createUser(User user) {
    // The first line causes the failure:
    InventoryServer.getUsers().removeIf(e -> e.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername()));
    InventoryServer.getUsers().add(user);
    InventoryServer.save();
}
```

The strange thing is, Jetty won't even start when this line exists. It gives me an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. I debugged the program at the time of the exception, and it seems it occurred in the method `SignatureParser.current()`. Several people online mentioned that this happens when you run Java 8 byte code with a library called asm, which, sure enough, I found to be a dependency of jetty-server. I couldn't update it though, since the most recent version of Jetty requires an older version of asm.

I guess a solution would be to simply not use any Java 8-specific features, but this seems like a pretty incomplete solution. Is there some way to fix this issue and keep using Java 8?

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 207
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF(ClassReader.java:1976)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:1951)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:515)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:850)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:723)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1120)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1093)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1089)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at edu.uhd.armyInventory.server.InventoryServer.<init>(InventoryServer.java:74)
    at edu.uhd.armyInventory.server.InventoryServer.main(InventoryServer.java:110)
Exception in thread "main" MultiException[javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-1da51a35@d8bf347==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer,-1,false, java.net.BindException: Address already in use]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at edu.uhd.armyInventory.server.InventoryServer.<init>(InventoryServer.java:74)
    at edu.uhd.armyInventory.server.InventoryServer.main(InventoryServer.java:110)
    Suppressed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-1da51a35@d8bf347==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer,-1,false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 207
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF(ClassReader.java:1976)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:1951)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:515)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:850)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:723)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1120)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1093)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1089)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:626)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: What version are you using? Jetty 9.2.0 should be okay with Java 8 features. You may need to update Jersey as well.

Comment: I'm using 9.3.5, but I will update Jersey and try it.

Comment: @TMBT Uhh.. that may have solved the problem. I updated Jersey to 2.22.1, and the server is starting with the lambda in place. Could you post an answer?

Comment: But for some reason, it's giving me another error when I try to access /user

Comment: I'll post my answer, but it sounds like you might have another question to ask soon. :)

Comment: Yes I think so. I seems to be related to another issue entirely.

Comment: Might have something to do with this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8035424

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to have a Jetty version of at least 9.2.0 and upgrade to Jersey 2.22.1 for Java 8 features support.

Comment: For anyone else out there facing the same problem, I recommend installing Jersey 2.8, since with this same setup I had, 2.22.1 caused the resources to be inaccessible. I'm not sure why, and I don't really care, because 2.8 resolved it.